# How to merge two df such that all value of df1 should be there in new df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose I have 2 df

```
df1
0    tata       A1
1     cts       A2
2    dell       A3
3     hp        A4

df2
  company  return
0    tata      71
1    dell      78
2     cts      27
3     hcl      23
```

I want to map all data of df2 with df1. If any data is missing just `Raise an exception` that this name is missing.

I merged the df1 and df2 successfully. but hp data wasn't mapped.How to throw the error

mine script
`pd.merge(df1, df2, on='company')`

Comment: after merging you can see if there is any nan and then give an error.

Comment: i am not getting any nan value. if values dont matches, it just ignores

Comment: do you want to check only the data names which are not matching or you want to create a merged table also?

Answer (score 2):

```
diff  = set(df1.company.values).difference(set(pd.merge(df1, df2, on='company').company.values))
if len(diff) >= 1: 
    raise Exception(f'values {diff} are missing')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `indicator` parameter:

```
df.merge(df2, on='company', how='left', indicator=True)

#   company return_x  return_y     _merge
# 0    tata       A1      71.0       both
# 1     cts       A2      27.0       both
# 2    dell       A3      78.0       both
# 3      hp       A4       NaN  left_only
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try out something like this:

```
d = dict(zip(df2['company'], df2['return']))
df1['return_1'] = df1.company.map(lambda x: d[x] if x in d else print(f"missing values is for : {x}"))
```

---

**output:**

```
missing values is for : hp

    company     return  return_1
0   tata        A1      71.0
1   cts         A2      27.0
2   dell        A3      78.0
3   hp          A4      NaN
```

---

If you are going for `pd.merge`, use `how` parameter and find out the row containing `nan` and raise an `error`.

```
u = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='company', how='left')
raise ValueError(f"missing values: {u[u.isna().any(axis=1)].company.values}")
```

---

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-2b6ac15ad749> in <module>
      1 u = pd.merge(df1, df, on='company')
----> 2 raise ValueError(f"missing values: {u[u.isna().any(axis=1)].company.values}")

ValueError: missing values: ['hp']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter if `_merge` column contains some `left_only` values and filter `company` column:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='company', indicator=True, how='left')

s = df.loc[df['_merge'].eq('left_only'), 'company']
if not s.empty: 
    raise Exception(f'values {", ".join(s)} are missing')
```